# Get pixels of a recyclerView item

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the pixels of an item of a recyclerView, let's say I have an horizontal recyclerView and all the items are the same size (from now), I'd like to know if it's possible to get the pixels of each item and detect the % in pixels of visibility of every item.

To have if it's visible I'm using this :

```
private boolean isViewVisible(View view, NestedScrollView scrollView) {
    Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    scrollView.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);
    float top = view.getY();
    float bottom = top + view.getHeight();
    return scrollBounds.top < top && scrollBounds.bottom > bottom;
}
```

Comment: You can try my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71560198/17133283)

Comment: @Sambhav.K but it works with horizontal scrollview? Can you provide an example so I can test it?

Comment: You can try to use width as a param wherever I have used height. That will do the task